# Why await - ed operation doesn't return if exceptions are thrown?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parallel-processing, async-await

I'm stuck in the parallel programing world. I have read many similar questions and answers here (as well as on other sites), but haven't been able to resolve the following situation.

I'm developing ASP.NET `ApiController` with an `async` method as follows:

```
<Route("signup")>
Public Async Function SignUpAsync(RegistrationInfo As RegisterAccountDto) As Task(Of IHttpActionResult)
    Dim result As IHttpActionResult = BadRequest()

    Dim userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get(Of UserManager)()

    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        Dim candidate As New User

        With candidate
            .Email = RegistrationInfo.Email
            .UserName = RegistrationInfo.UserName
        End With

        Dim x = Await userManager.CreateAsync(candidate, RegistrationInfo.Password)

        result = Ok()
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

I do, intentionally, let an exception to occur during the `CreateAsync` method - i.e. I've extended the `User` class to contain some mandatory (`NOT NULL`) properties, but I didn't supply their values.
Clearly, in the output window is shown that multiple exceptions are thrown, regarding missing values.

My problem is, that the code after the `Dim x = Await userManager.CreateAsync(candidate, RegistrationInfo.Password)` line never gets executed, nor the exceptions are thrown.

Through Fiddler, I'm making a POST request to the above mentioned method. The returned result is 500 (Internal Server Error), which seems to be correct in the given situation. But still, why am I not receiving these errors in my code?

Much of the posts on the subjects I've read, propagate `ConfigureAwait(False)`.
I gave it a try - no luck.

Also, I've ensured that I'm targeting framework version 4.5 - actually I'm targeting 4.5.1

I've read that `Async Sub` (`async void` methods in C#) behaves similarly to what I'm describing,
but my method is an `Async Function` and returns `Task(Of T)`

I did `<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true" />` under the `<runtime>` into web.config - again, no change.

So, as I said - I'm stuck. Any ideas?

#### Edit

It turns out that the problem doesn't lies within the awaited operation at all. My first post wasn't correct as I stated that the exceptions are not throw. They are, but VS 2013 doesn't break, whether or not the exception is in synchronous or asynchronous code. Which continues to amaze me. Probably there is something with my VS settings, I hope.

So far I double checked the Enable Tools -> Options -> Debbuging ->Just My Code and Debug -> Exceptions -> User unhandled are checked, but still, VS doesn't break when I introduce `Throw New ArgumentException` in place of the awaited op :/

Comment: You're not receiving the errors in your code because you don't have a `Catch` block to receive them in.

Comment: Sounds to me like exceptions are thrown. Internal server error is what happens when exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Re: edit - the exceptions *are* being thrown, and they *are* being handled (by some asp.net infrastructure that turns them into the 500 status code). If you want *your* code to deal with them, either add a `Catch` block or install an appropriate handler (exact form depends on whether you're dealing with Web API or MVC or plain old webforms) for unhandled exceptions.